# AFTER EACH ROW vs BEFORE EACH ROW Triggers (Locks)

Tags: oracle, database-trigger

In earlier versions of Oracle documentation, there was a note about the differences of BEFORE EACH ROW and AFTER EACH ROW triggers (Other than the obvious, AFTER EACH ROW triggers fire AFTER the DML has executed on the row and you can't update the :new pseudorecord).  The note from the 10g documentation stated: "Unlike BEFORE row triggers, AFTER row triggers lock rows." [(Source)](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/triggers.htm#i6052)

However, I can't find the same note in the 12cR2 or 19c documentation.  So, I have two questions:

1. Is this still applicable in 12cR2/19c?
2. Is the lock that is mentioned an extension (or delay to release) the lock which was obtained during the DML? Or, is it a separate lock obtained by the trigger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To those of you who expressed interest in this question.  I posed the same question to AskTOM and received a response.  You can find it [here](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/asktom.search?tag=after-each-row-vs-before-each-row-triggers-locks)

tl;dr:  The old documentation is wrong.  The lock is obtained prior to the BEFORE triggers, so all triggers are subject to the lock.